HT66F0021 with ADC -- Holtek controller
I am using HT66F0021 controller interfacing with adc. I am new to this controller.I am not able to read the ADC value my condition is not becoming true and I am not having uart to print the data. I have attached my code for reference. I am using AN2 channel.
    #include "HT66F0021.h"
    
    void Delay_ms(unsigned int count);
    void McuConfig(void);
    void GpioConfig(void);
    void AdcConfig(void);
    void AdcMeasure(void);
    
    unsigned int AdcResult = 0;
    
    void main()
    {
        McuConfig();

    while (1)
    {
        AdcMeasure(); // Update AdcResult with the current ADC value

        if (AdcResult > 512) // Compare ADC result
        {
            _pa5 = 1; // Set PA5 high
        }
        else
        {
            _pa5 = 0; // Set PA5 low
        }

        Delay_ms(100); // Delay for stability
    }
}

void Delay_ms(unsigned int count)
{
    char i, j;
    for (j = 0; j < count; j++)
    {
        i = 100;
        while (i)
        {
            _clrwdt(); // Clear watchdog timer
            _nop(); // No operation (multiple for timing adjustment)
            _nop();
            _nop();
            _nop();
            _nop();
            _nop();
            _nop();
            _nop();
            _nop();
            _nop();
            _nop();
            _nop();
            _nop();
            _nop();
            _nop();
            _nop();
            i--;
        }
    }
}

void McuConfig(void)
{
    GpioConfig();
    AdcConfig();
}

void GpioConfig(void)
{
    _pac = 0b10011011; // Configure port A as needed
    _pa5 = 0; // Set PA5 to low initially
    _pac5 = 0; // Configure PA5 as output
}

void AdcConfig(void)
{
    _sadol = 0; // Clear ADC data low byte
    _sadoh = 0; // Clear ADC data high byte
    
    _sadc0 = 0b00010000; // Enable adrfs bit
    _sadc1 = 0b00000100; // Configure ADC settings (e.g. clock,mode)
    _pasr = 0b01100000;  // Select ADC channel (e.g., AN2 as input)
}

void AdcMeasure(void)
{
    _start = 1; // Start ADC conversion
    while (_adbz); // Wait for ADC conversion to complete
    _start = 0; // Reset the start bit

    // Read ADC result
    AdcResult = (_sadoh << 8) | _sadol; // Combine high and low byte

}


You have to selected ADC external channel in _sadc0 register
_sadc0 = 0b00110010; //AN2 selected
ADC converstion is started when _start bit is set from low high and again low
void AdcMeasure(void)
{
_start = 0; _start = 1; _start = 0; // Start ADC conversion
while (_adbz); // Wait for ADC conversion to complete
// Read ADC result
AdcResult = (_sadoh << 8) | _sadol; // Combine high and low byte

}
